# How to stop sessions overwriting each other when multiple users login to the system using same browser?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on with login systems using PHP and MYSQL. Generally, what I do is starts a session in my login page and retrive role id from my database if user username and password matches.
**login.php**

```
 <?php
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    # I retrieve $RID from my database I didn't put that line below.
    $_SESSION['RID']=$RID;

    if($RID==1)
    {
    header("location:adm/index.php");
    }


     else if($RID==2)
       {
          header("location:user");
       }
       else if($RID==3) {
           header("location:emp");
       }
       else {
         exit();
       }
?>
```

In my index page I compare the role id. If that role id has permissions I will allow him.
**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['RID']) && $_SESSION['RID'] == 1)
{
  header("location:index.php")
}
else {
  exit();
}

?>
```

The problem I am facing is there are two users A and B. A logged into the application and before he logged out B also logged in using the same browser in a new tab. In, that case I am destroying all previous sessions when a user try to logged in. So, user B does his work and he reenters A's tab. But, already A's session key was changed by B's session key.
But, I know Browsers generally maintain a single session per browser instance. But, how to make this work and how can I login two persons without overwriting their sessions. Or, I need to destroy both sessions and log them out if they using same browser.

Comment: You can not maintain a session per tab with native PHP cookie-based sessions. I'd just update the login page so that it doesn't allow logins if a user is already logged in.

Comment: @Jeto. Thank you for your suggestion. But, what they actually say is whatever operations you do to make sessions work on multiple tabs it results in hack. So, I kinda got something but at the same time the question remains unsolved.

Comment: _"the question remains unsolved"_ Because it's not solvable. You either implement a hack, or you don't allow multiple logins. Pick one.

Comment: The OP's question is about  TWO users. So telling him not to allow a login if a user is already logged in is not useful. I see this question and the so-called "answers" a lot, because I have situations where my users have more than one account on my domain. When they log in to **a second account** on another tab, the session data crosses over when they switch back to the first tab. I don't understand why people have to give sarcastic answers to a real problem.

Comment: Use incognito if this is for development, doubt you would need this in real life